# Camera doesn't work after compilation

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I use **Ionic Framework**.

Camera works perfectly in **Ionic View**. But it doesn't work after compilitaion on iOS.

Please, help to find out what is the problem.

Camera code in **services.js**:

```
app.factory('FileService', function() {
  var images;
  var IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY = 'dav-images';

  function getImages() {
    var img = window.localStorage.getItem(IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY);
    if (img) {
      images = JSON.parse(img);
    } else {
      images = [];
    }
    return images;
  };

  function addImage(img) {
    images.push(img);
    window.localStorage.setItem(IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(images));
  };

  return {
    storeImage: addImage,
    images: getImages
  }
});

app.factory('ImageService', function($cordovaCamera, FileService, $q, $cordovaFile) {

  function optionsForType(type) {
    var source;
    switch (type) {
      case 0:
        source = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
        break;
      case 1:
        source = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
        break;
    }
    return {
      quality: 90,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: source,
      allowEdit: false,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation:true
    };
  }

  function saveMedia(type) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      var options = optionsForType(type);

      $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageBase64) {
        FileService.storeImage(imageBase64);
      });
    })
  }
  return {
    handleMediaDialog: saveMedia
  }
});
```

Camera code in **controllers.js:**

```
app.controller('CameraController', function($scope, $cordovaDevice, $cordovaFile, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaEmailComposer, $ionicActionSheet, ImageService, FileService) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $scope.images = FileService.images();
    $scope.$apply();
  });

  $scope.addMedia = function() {
    $scope.hideSheet = $ionicActionSheet.show({
      buttons: [
        { text: 'Take photo' },
        { text: 'Photo from library' }
      ],
      titleText: 'Add images',
      cancelText: 'Cancel',
      buttonClicked: function(index) {
        $scope.addImage(index);
      }
    });
  }

  $scope.addImage = function(type) {
    $scope.hideSheet();
    ImageService.handleMediaDialog(type).then(function() {
      $scope.$apply();
    });
  }

  $scope.sendEmail = function() {
    if ($scope.images != null && $scope.images.length > 0) {
      var mailImages = [];
      var savedImages = $scope.images;
      for (var i = 0; i < savedImages.length; i++) {
        mailImages.push('base64:attachment'+i+'.jpg//' + savedImages[i]);
      }
      $scope.openMailComposer(mailImages);
    }
  }

  $scope.openMailComposer = function(attachments) {
    var bodyText = '<html><h2>My Images</h2></html>';
    var email = {
      to: '',
      attachments: attachments,
      subject: 'Devdactic Images',
      body: bodyText,
      isHtml: true
    };

    $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email, function(){
      console.log('email view dismissed');
    }, this);
  }
});
```

Comment: According to what you are saying, I believe you have just forgotten to do :  `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`. If this is not working, please post your code and tell us what really doesn't work.

Comment: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera was added. Here is the link of the code: https://github.com/vitaly-safonov/Hair-plus

Comment: Please describe more your problem. What is the error that you get or the comportement ? Have you tried to look in safari console ? Also for your code please learn [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We will not read all your code to find where you use camera.

Comment: Added camera code in my question.

Comment: Thank you. Please also describe what is not working and verify console

Comment: Camera doesn't work after compilation on iOS. But it works in Ionic View. Console say nothing :) - because it works in view.

Comment: What does it mean doesn't work ? Do you have any crash ? Is it opening something ?

Comment: When i push "Take Photo" - nothing happens at all. But it works in Ionic View.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it ? By verifying if it is calling `addImage` and then `saveMedia` from service ? (You can use breakpoints or `console.log` as you wish) Also verify if you don't have errors you can print it in catch of promise if it is not already printing it. Also have you uninstalled the app and reinstall ?

Comment: How i can check the function call in the build?

Comment: See this answer to debug : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787839/debugging-cordova-phonegap-code-on-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this problem you need to compile an app with **XCode**.
After **XCode** compilation camera works correctly.

Probably, the problem with camera was caused by **Ionic** compilation.