# How to display a QR code in phonegap

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I'm trying to display a QR_CODE. I get an alert that I have an object, but I can't find the function or property that displays the actual QR_CODE.

My code goes this way:

```
BarcodeScanner.encode (BarcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, 'Hello World')
  .then ((success) => {
    alert (success);
  }), (error) => {
    alert (error);
  }
```

I get this alert:

[image]

Any ideas? My guess was to `alert (success.QR_CODE)`, but y get a message of `undefined`.

Comment: The docs doesn't seem to be really good.To help debug the object, use `console.log(success)` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787839/debugging-cordova-phonegap-code-on-ios to find how to access to Safari console

Comment: I just came here to post the answer! I did exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the answer.

What I had to do is to declare a property inside my class. For me it's called `urlImage`. Then, inside the encode function:

```
BarcodeScanner.encode (BarcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, 'Hello World')
  .then ((success) => {
    this.urlImage = success.file;
  }), (error) => {
    alert (error);
  }
```

Then, in my html code:

`<img src="{{imageUrl}}"/>`

And that's it.